# Remove Child from Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, xamarin

In Xamarin, how can I get the current Layout so that I can remove a Child from the Layout?

Here is my code:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.AutoLinkTextView);

TextView Email = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewEmail);
Email.Text = "Test Email of me@me.com";

TextView Phone = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewPhone);
Phone.Text = "Test Phone of 0800 64 64 64";

TextView Web = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.TextViewWeb);
Web.Text = "Test Address of http://www.google.com" + "\n" + "Test Address of http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

In my AutoLinkTextView Layout I have a TextView with the following id that I wish to remove from the Layout:

```
android:id="@+id/TextViewMap"
```

Can I please have some help to do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Can I have some help with the code?

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById (0);
View ViewToRemove = layout.GetChildAt (1);
layout.RemoveView (ViewToRemove);
```

With the above code, none of the TextView objects are shown at all.

Comment: you can use removeView() function.

Answer (score 4):

First give some id to Main layout. like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
//All ur textviews
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in onCreate() write this code:

```
LinearLayout _linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(Resource.id.linearLayout);
TextView textViewMap = (TextView) findViewById(Resource.id.TextViewMap); 
_linear.removeView(textViewMap);
```